# Refresh Element in QML

Tags: radio-button, refresh, desktop, reload, qml

I have a RadioButton in my QML Desktop Application, and when I set it to unchecked, It really becomes unchecked, but I can't see that untill it contains mouse. I tried a lot of ways to resolve it, and didn't find any good one. so I decided to refresh the page, or even just thr RadioButton, in order to set the RadioButton to it's really state, and I hope that after the refreshing the button will be shown as unchecked one.
Do you have any idea how to refresh or reload it? Thanks ahead!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems you just got bitten by a bug the QML components for the desktop (or what kind of radio button component you are using?). Not overly surprising, this is still unreleased code not intended for production use.

Refreshing the radio button as in unload it and reload it just after that is possible with the help of the [`Loader`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qml-loader.html) element. Just clear the `source` attribute temporarily.

Comment: Thanks, @sebasgo, This was what I did at last, and it is really a good idea.